# StringUtils Overload chop method

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I want to overload the chop method of `StringUtils` to remove the last character if it is a backslash`(\)`.

Is it possible to overload the function or I need to use an if condition?

Comment: Do you mean override?

Comment: If you wanna override it then it's not possible in the classic sense because it's a static method.

Comment: `StringUtils` is a class from Apache Commons library right? Overloading means you want to create a method with the same name but different params (basically!). What are you going to do ? Donwload apache commons source code, change the class build jar and use it ?

Comment: Honestly my boss told me to try to do so and that it would be muche more cleaner! But I have no clue how to do it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not this instead?

```
StringUtils.removeEnd(s,"\\")
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, use an `if` statement. You can't override a static method and it would be too much anyway to create it's own class just for that.

I have an alternative that I personally like:

```
public static String chopIf(Predicate<String> p, String s) {
    if (p.test(s)) {
        return s.substring(0, s.length()-1); //or StringUtils.chop(s)
    }
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "qwert\\";
    System.out.println(chopIf(s -> s.endsWith("\\"), test));
}
```

Something like that. Then you can use it for any character. Tweak it according to need.

Comment: I do like it actually! It's pretty smart.